# Class to form_for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, form-for

I don't get why this return me a error

```
<%= form_for(@user), :html => {:class => 'form-connexion'} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
D:/xxxxxxx/app/views/users/edit.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end ...end= form_for(@user), :html => {:class => 'form-connexion'}... ... ^
D:/xxxxxxx/app/views/users/edit.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end ...{:class => 'form-connexion'} do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe... ... ^
D:/xxxxxxx/app/views/users/edit.html.erb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

I'm using the same syntax in another file and it's ok.

Comment: It should probably be `<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:class => 'form-connexion'}) do |f| %>`. The whole thing should be wrapped in `(..)` or write it as `<%= form_for @user, :html => {:class => 'form-connexion'} do |f| %>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
form_for(@user), :html => ...
```

That end bracket, after `@user`, closes the call for the method `#form_for`, so it doesn't know what to do with the comma and then the hash.

Change that to:

```
form_for(@user, :html => ...) do |f|
```

And you'll be good. Or even no brackets:

```
form_for @user, :html => ... do |f|
```

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark it as the answer to your question for future developers.