# How to style a form_for in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to ruby on rails and I need some help figuring out how to style a form I made.
This is the code for the form inside of my html file:

```
 <%= form_for @article do |t| %>
    <%= t.text_field :title, :html => { :class => 'title' } %>
    <%= t.text_area :body, :html => { :class => 'body' } %>
    <%= t.submit 'Create', :html => { :class => 'create' } %>
```

Comment: How you style it depends upon what you want to do with style. Do you mean you want to add a class to the `form` element? Also, I don't think you need, `:html => { :class => 'title' }`, for example, but simply, `:class => 'title'` should suffice.

Comment: Yes I want to add a class to the form element?

Comment: No I have not, but i'll give it a try now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class to form\_for Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557044/class-to-form-for-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an error message

Comment: See the link I provided

Comment: Now I have the class on the form

Comment: How come I access the tags on the specific form components ?
Like title or body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

`<%= form_for @article do |t| %>
    <%= t.text_field :title, :class => 'class_name' %>`